# Bold text on excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have a spread sheet with 2 tabs, 1 is for internal use and the other is the client copy. We key all cost and descriptions on the internal copy and this populates to the client copy.
My question is I would like to high light information in the description by bold text or underlining the words, I can do this on the internal copy but it doesn't reflect this onto the client copy

This is the formula that is in the cell on the client copy 
   =IF('INTERNAL USE'!H13=0,"    ",'INTERNAL USE'!H13)
Are we able to do this and if so what do I need to add to the formula to do this

Thanks
Kylie

Comment: Can you not just select the cells on the client copy that need to be bold or underlined and format the text in those cells to display as bold or underlined?

Comment: You can't do that with standard functions.  A workaround could be to use macros.

Comment: With the workaround what is macros

Comment: Bandersnatch - We tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirement?  Are only some words in the description highlighted ("This solution is **really expensive**")?  And if so, is there a rule to which words are highlighted?

Comment: Also I think you probably want to check [`ISBLANK()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) instead of `=0`.  Try `=IF(ISBLANK('INTERNAL USE'!H13),"",'INTERNAL USE'!H13)`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an easy way to do this.  As [an MS Excel MVP says](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/552486-pick-up-format-from-another-cell.html#post_1623536):

> Formulas and Functions can return result only.  They cannot change or copy formatting.

There are 2 possible solutions to your problem that I can see:

## 1 Conditional formatting

If the source cells are being formatted with [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rules, apply the same rules to the destination cells.

## 2 VBA scripting

[This user](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/159033-include-formatting-when-referencing-cell#post_937450) provides some helpful VBA scripts and instructions for another user on how to do exactly this, but it's not simple and will require tweaking to suit your requirements.

> Place the following code in a standard module:

```
Public Sub CopyFormat(rng As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If rng.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
If Left(rng.Value, 1) = "#" Then
    Ref = Mid(rng.Value, 2, Len(rng.Value) - 1)
    Range(Ref).Copy
    rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    rng.Formula = "=" & Ref  'COMMENT OUT IF REFERRED CELL VALUE NOT REQUIRED
    'rng.Value = ""  'ACTIVATE IF REFERRED CELL VALUE NOT REQUIRED
End If
End Sub
```

> Place the following code in the Worksheet_Change event routine of each sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
CopyFormat Target
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
With Worksheets("Hidden")
On Error Resume Next
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range(.Range("Z1").Value).Copy
    Range(.Range("Z1").Value).Dependents.Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
If Err = 0 Then
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End If
.Range("Z1") = Target.Address
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

> In the calling cell enter the formula but replace the "=" with a pound sign "#" (without the quotes):
>
> Instead of the formula for A5 being =A1 it will be #A1
>   Instead of the formula for Sheet2 cell A1 being =Sheet1!A1, it will be #Sheet1!A1
>
> It can be used to carry the value and the formatting from cell to cell on the same sheet or between different sheets. It will also carry the comment from the referred cell as well. If you want to copy just the formatting without the value then change rng.formula = "=" & Ref to Rng.value = ""